# C- printf() is writing over my variables

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm working on a practice exercise and it seems printf() is writing over my variable somewhere. I'm working with a structure containing a pointer to an array of pointers to structures so I'm sure I've assigned something slightly wrong somewhere.

```
    int dictionary_add(struct dictionary* d,
                    const char * const english,
                    const char * const foreign){
    /* ROLE         Adds a new wordPair made of strdup copies of the parameter strings
                    to a dictionary d

       RETURNS      0   if everything went fine

       PARAMETERS   d           the dictionary to work with
                    english     string representing the english part of the new wordPair
                    foreign     string representing the foreign part of the new wordPair
    */




    //Determine where in the array the wordPair is going.
    int location;
    location=((d->size)-(d->nbwords))-1;
    printf("Adding data to array location: %i\n\n",location);


    //Build the wordPair
    const struct wordPair newPair={english,foreign};

    //Add the wordPair
    d->data[0]=&newPair;

    //***************This is where the problem shows up***************
    printf("Added english:%s\n",d->data[0]->englishWord);
    //d->data[0]=&newPair; //When uncommeted, program doesn't crash.
    printf("Added english:%s\n",d->data[0]->englishWord);
    d->nbwords++;
    return 0;
}
```

How this is called from main():

```
const char* english=malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
const char* foreign=malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
strcpy(english,"hello");
strcpy(foreign,"holla");
```

Where the dictionary is created:

```
    struct dictionary *dictionary_build(int size){
     /* ROLE        Allocate and initialize a new dictionary structure able to accomodate a number of
                    pairs of words specified by the size parameter
       RETURNS      Address of new dictionary, if allocation was successfull.
                    NULL otherwize
       PARAMETERS   The size of the dictionary to make
     */
    struct dictionary *d=malloc(sizeof(struct dictionary));

    d->size=size;
    d->nbwords=0;

    struct wordpair* wordPairs[size]; //create array of pointers to wordpairs


    d->data=&wordPairs; //Set pointer to array of pointers to wordpairs

    return d;
}
```

The structures:

```
struct wordPair {
       char* englishWord;
       char* foreignWord;
};

struct dictionary {
       struct wordPair ** data;
       int nbwords;
       int size;
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help. And I'm not opposed to the idea that my entire design misses the point. I can change anything outside of the struct definitions and the expected parameters.

Comment: `wordPairs` is allocated on the stack, it's going to go out of scope immediately after `return d`, so you shouldn't be retaining a pointer to it in `d`. Use `malloc()` to allocate it instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
    struct wordpair* wordPairs[size];
    d->data=&wordPairs;
    return d;
}
```

`wordPairs` has automatic storage, and its lifetime will end when the function returns. It's undefined behavior to attempt to refer to an object after the end of its life, yet you are retaining a pointer to it within `d` which you then try to dereference in `dictionary_add()`.

Use something like `d->data = malloc(size * sizeof(struct wordpair *));` or similar, instead. Don't forget to check the return from `malloc()` to determine whether it succeeded, and (usually) to `free()` everything when you're done.